Bazel build not working in a folder with non ASCII (Japanese) characters
I'm using English Mint21 with Bazel 7.1.0.
If I build a simple hello-world C++ type project in a folder with Japanese characters in it, I get an error -
/tmp/ワーク:$ bazel build //...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Client cwd '/tmp/ワーク' is not inside workspace '/tmp/???'
/tmp/ワーク:$ 

I'm not sure that the exact contents of BUILD etc would matter as it fails very early on.
I did some searching and found the issue reported in 2017 but the ticket was closed without fixing: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2550
Is there some flag I need to use to make it work? I presume my environment is wrong in some way as there's not much mention of the problem on the internet.
Thanks.

I would clearly classify that as a bug. Please report it as one.

OK. I've raised it here - https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/23859
